# Is there a shorter way to find classes

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was wondering if there was a shorter way to achieve this kind of css selector :

```
.post.quote, .post.photo, .post.video {
...
}
```

Comment: Other than modifying the HTML, no.

Comment: try http://lesscss.org/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the classes `photo`, `video`, and `quote` will only ever appear under `post`, maybe you could consider rearranging the styles to be more specific for `post`. Then just:

```
.photo, .video, .quote { /*...*/ }
```

should have the same effect.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but not directly through CSS: - SASS (http://sass-lang.com/) for example, allows you to do:

```
.user.post{
    margin-top:10px;
    .photo{}
    .video{}
}
```

which becomes

```
.user.post{margin-top:10px;}
.user.post .photo{}
.user.post .video{}
```

or if you can only use js, theres LESS (http://lesscss.org/):

```
.bordered {
      border-top: dotted 1px black;
      border-bottom: solid 2px black;
      color:blue;
      font-weight:bold;
      margin-left:20px;
    }

.post, .video {
  .child, .sibling {
      .parent & { color: black; }
      & & { .bordered; }
  }
}
```

becomes

```
.bordered {
  border-top: dotted 1px black;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
.parent .post .child,
.parent .video .child,
.parent .post .sibling,
.parent .video .sibling {
  color: black;
}
.post .child .post .child,
.post .child .video .child,
.post .child .post .sibling,
.post .child .video .sibling,
.video .child .post .child,
.video .child .video .child,
.video .child .post .sibling,
.video .child .video .sibling,
.post .sibling .post .child,
.post .sibling .video .child,
.post .sibling .post .sibling,
.post .sibling .video .sibling,
.video .sibling .post .child,
.video .sibling .video .child,
.video .sibling .post .sibling,
.video .sibling .video .sibling {
  border-top: dotted 1px black;
  border-bottom: solid 2px black;
  color: blue;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-left: 20px;
}
```

Comment: All right, thanks !
I can't use SASS for this project but it's good to know :)

Comment: I personally like LESS CSS better, but yes these 2 are the best possibilities for this. They also have a lot of other features you might be interested in like shortening, variables, and JS parsing

Comment: How... is this __shorter__? Ugh, my bad. Please try to reformulate the example, though...

Comment: @icedwater how's that for a better example?

Comment: Thanks @Max, I can feel your violence from here. It is still quite excessive but at least it's clearer. ;)

Comment: hahaha, it's kind of hard to show with a little bit of css, but when you have a few hundred lines, it's quite amazing! :-)